# Read UID of java card within the program

Tags: uniqueidentifier, javacard, apdu

I am new to java card development.i want to read the java card UID within the program.i want to use that key for future usages.i don't want to send the apdu commands and get the UID.is there any way to read the UID within code???
Thanks
SSv

Comment: Why not read the UID (by "sending APDU commands") and store that during personalization of your applet?

Comment: Thanks martijno,i know how to read uid from sending apdu commands from device to card.but i want to know how to use some apdu commands within java card application.then i want to encrypt the uid and send back to the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested by me, but there appears to be a `UID` class with a static `getStaticUID()` method in the proprietary NXP APIs on JCOP.

If you have Eclipse with NXP JCOP tools installed, look into plugins of your Eclipse installation folder to find a `*smartmx.targetpacks.smartmx_*/apis` folder which contains (zipped) Javadocs for NXP proprietary API.

As far as I know there is no standardized way in Java Card or Global Platform to get to the UID.

Comment: It would make sense because of the support for the MIFARE protocol in the SmartMX chips (if they are configured to support MIFARE, of course).

Comment: thanks your response.any way i want to know what is card image number(CIN) and is it a unique value and length of the CIN.i read the GP 2.1.1 document and it says inside java card i can read CIN.Thanks